# Outlook Accept / Decline buttons don't show up for Icalendar

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

I want to send calendar invitations from my Laravel application. I want these invitations to show the accept / decline / propose new time / maybe buttons inside Outlook, but for some reason I can't get them to show up

I need this because I want to achieve this:

[image: Calendar invitation]

My code:

```
$icalendar = IcalendarUtil::genEvent(
    array('Me', 'me@example.com'),
    new DateTime(),
    null,
    array(
        'example@example.com' => 'John Doe'
    ),
    'Test subject',
    'Test location',
    'Test Description',
    true,
    true
);

Mail::send('nada', array(), function($message) use($icalendar)
{
    $message->from('example@example.com', 'John Doe');
    $message->to('me@example.com')->subject('Test Calendar Event');

    $attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($icalendar, 'event.ics', 'text/calendar');

    $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/calendar');
    $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '7bit');
    $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailer', 'Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0');
    $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('method', 'REQUEST');
    $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('charset', 'iso-8859-1');

    $message->attachAttachment($attachment);
});
```

`$message->attachAttachment($attachment);`
is a function I added to `Illuminate\Mail\Message.php` to add a Swift_Attachment created with newInstance. Code:

```
public function attachAttachment($attachment)
{
    $this->prepAttachment($attachment);
}
```

The IcalendarUtil class was provided to me by `Arun Poudel`:

```
<?php

/**
 * iCalendar util
 */
class IcalendarUtil
{

/**
 * Generates a iCalendar event.
 *
 * @param array $organizer
 * @param DateTime $from_date
 * @param DateTime $to_date
 * @param array $attendees
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $location
 * @param string $description
 * @param bool $all_day_event
 * @param bool $rsvp
 * @return string
 * @static
 * @throws cbmException
 */
static public function genEvent(array $organizer, DateTime $from_date, DateTime $to_date = null, array $attendees = null, $subject = null, $location = null, $description = null, $all_day_event = false, $rsvp = true)
{
    if (!$all_day_event && $to_date === null)
    {
        throw new Exception('to_date is required when the event is not an all day event');
    }
    $organizer_name = $organizer[0];
    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    $ical .= "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n";
    $ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
    $ical .= sprintf("TZID:%s\r\n", date('T'));
    $ical .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTSTART:16010101T000000\r\n";
    $ical .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0545\r\n";
    $ical .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0545\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:STANDARD\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= sprintf("UID:%s\r\n", rand());

    $ical .= sprintf("ORGANIZER;CN=\"%s\":MAILTO:%s\r\n", $organizer_name, $organizer[1]);
    foreach ($attendees as $email => $name)
    {
        $ical .= sprintf("ATTENDEE;");
        if ($name !== null)
        {
            $ical .= sprintf("CN=\"%s\";", $name);
        }
        if($rsvp)
        {
            $ical .= sprintf("RSVP=TRUE:");
        }
        $ical .= sprintf("mailto:%s;\r\n", $email);
    }
    $ical .= sprintf("LOCATION:%s\r\n", $location);
    $ical .= sprintf("DTSTAMP:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat());
    $ical .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\r\n";
    $ical .= sprintf("DTSTART:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat($from_date));
    if (!$all_day_event)
    {
        $ical .= sprintf("DTEND:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat($to_date));
    }
    $ical .= sprintf("SUMMARY:%s\r\n", $subject);
    $ical .= "TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:1\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE\r\n";
    $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\r\n";
    $ical .= sprintf("X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN=\"%s\":MAILTO:%s\r\n", $organizer_name, $organizer[1]);
    $ical .= sprintf("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:%s\r\n", "<p>" . preg_replace('/\R/', "</p><p>", $description) . "</p>");
    $ical .= sprintf("X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\r\n");
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
    $ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
    $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";
    return $ical;
}

static protected function getDateTimeInUTCFormat(DateTime $date = null)
{
    if ($date === null)
    {
        $date = new DateTime();
    }
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return $date->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
}

}
```

The email shows up simply as an email with a .ics attachment. What am I doing wrong? Why are the RSVP buttons not showing up?

Comment: see the pure php implementation here : https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/sending-outlookemail-calendar-events-php/ , you can attach calender at the end of the message following this approach.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about Laravel here. I have already linked to a working example in my post, but I need it to work with Laravel's Mail class.

Comment: Yes thats why I have not put it as an answer, you could follow this approach to prepare the attachment which you can then attach to laravel email. However the answer by arun seems more convenient in your case.

Comment: Any luck with the second answer I provided?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want to set the type of the whole email as text/calendar. You might need to add email body as well. So, my suggestion will be to attach the calendar and then set the mine type:

```
$message->attach('something.ics', array('mime' => 'text/calendar'))
```

EDIT:

Use this class to generate your iCal

```
<?php

/**
 * iCalendar util
 */
class IcalendarUtil
{

    /**
     * Generates a iCalendar event.
     *
     * @param array $organizer
     * @param DateTime $from_date
     * @param DateTime $to_date
     * @param array $attendees
     * @param string $subject
     * @param string $location
     * @param string $description
     * @param bool $all_day_event
     * @param bool $rsvp
     * @return string
     * @static
     * @throws cbmException
     */
    static public function genEvent(array $organizer, DateTime $from_date, DateTime $to_date = null, array $attendees = null, $subject = null, $location = null, $description = null, $all_day_event = false, $rsvp = true)
    {
        if (!$all_day_event && $to_date === null)
        {
            throw new Exception('to_date is required when the event is not an all day event');
        }
        $organizer_name = $organizer[0];
        $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
        $ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
        $ical .= "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n";
        $ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\r\n";
        $ical .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
        $ical .= sprintf("TZID:%s\r\n", date('T'));
        $ical .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
        $ical .= "DTSTART:16010101T000000\r\n";
        $ical .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0545\r\n";
        $ical .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0545\r\n";
        $ical .= "END:STANDARD\r\n";
        $ical .= "END:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
        $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
        $ical .= sprintf("UID:%s\r\n" . rand());

        $ical .= sprintf("ORGANIZER;CN=\"%s\":MAILTO:%s\r\n", $organizer_name, $organizer[1]);
        foreach ($attendees as $email => $name)
        {
            $ical .= sprintf("ATTENDEE;");
            if ($name !== null)
            {
                $ical .= sprintf("CN=\"%s\";", $name);
            }
            if($rsvp)
            {
                $ical .= sprintf("RSVP=TRUE:");
            }
            $ical .= sprintf("mailto:%s;\r\n", $email);
        }
        $ical .= sprintf("LOCATION:%s\r\n", $location);
        $ical .= sprintf("DTSTAMP:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat());
        $ical .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\r\n";
        $ical .= sprintf("DTSTART:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat($from_date));
        if (!$all_day_event)
        {
            $ical .= sprintf("DTEND:%s\r\n", self::getDateTimeInUTCFormat($to_date));
        }
        $ical .= sprintf("SUMMARY:%s\r\n", $subject);
        $ical .= "TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:1\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE\r\n";
        $ical .= "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\r\n";
        $ical .= sprintf("X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN=\"%s\":MAILTO:%s\r\n", $organizer_name, $organizer[1]);
        $ical .= sprintf("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:%s\r\n", "<p>" . preg_replace('/\R/', "</p><p>", $description) . "</p>");
        $ical .= sprintf("X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\r\n");
        $ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
        $ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
        $ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
        $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
        $ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
        $ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
        $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";
        return $ical;
    }

    static protected function getDateTimeInUTCFormat(DateTime $date = null)
    {
        if ($date === null)
        {
            $date = new DateTime();
        }
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        return $date->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
    }

}
```

Also, you might need to set some custom headers in the email.

```
encoding = '7bit'
header = 'Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0' // Not sure if this is needed, but we might need to fool microsoft
```

Comment: But then I don't get the accept, tentative and decline buttons.

Comment: @Basaa Yes you do. Can you attach  other details like the ics file etc you are sending when sending it via attachment and when no doing so in your original question?

Comment: Thanks for the class. The file generates file but still no accept/decline buttons. If I send the email to a Gmail account it does show the event inside the email though. Why is Outlook not showing it?

Comment: @Basaa Did you set the encoding and header? Does it work if you send it to gmail account?

Comment: Yes... Although... Jeez Laravel mail is complicated. I have to set the headers on the attachment right? How do I set attachment headers in Laravel? Trying to generate an attachment with Swift_Attachment::newInstance(...) gives me all kinds of weird fopen errors. Could you please provide me with a small Laravel snippet that uses the IcalendarUtil class to send an email? I have spent so many hours on this and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: The IcalendarUtil class posted on my previous was used in a
>   Symfony project. And was hoping to work the same way as

As you have already included almost all of my previous answer to your OP, I am posting some hacks I made to the laravel Mailer class for it to work and why it was need.

This is the original code from `Mailer.php`

```
/**
 * Send a new message using a view.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $view
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @return mixed
 */
public function send($view, array $data, $callback)
{
    // First we need to parse the view, which could either be a string or an array
    // containing both an HTML and plain text versions of the view which should
    // be used when sending an e-mail. We will extract both of them out here.
    list($view, $plain, $raw) = $this->parseView($view);

    $data['message'] = $message = $this->createMessage();

    $this->callMessageBuilder($callback, $message);

    // Once we have retrieved the view content for the e-mail we will set the body
    // of this message using the HTML type, which will provide a simple wrapper
    // to creating view based emails that are able to receive arrays of data.
    $this->addContent($message, $view, $plain, $raw, $data);

    $message = $message->getSwiftMessage();

    return $this->sendSwiftMessage($message);
}
```

As you can see that laravel is doing some black magic with the message even after the callback, which is bad for us. Now, if we dig more into the black magic function `addContent` then you will see that the content type is forced by the type of parameters we have sent while initially calling the view class:

```
/**
 * Add the content to a given message.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  string  $plain
 * @param  string  $raw
 * @param  array   $data
 * @return void
 */
protected function addContent($message, $view, $plain, $raw, $data)
{
    if (isset($view))
    {
        $message->setBody($this->getView($view, $data), 'text/html');
    }

    if (isset($plain))
    {
        $message->addPart($this->getView($plain, $data), 'text/plain');
    }

    if (isset($raw))
    {
        $message->addPart($raw, 'text/plain');
    }
}
```

Now to mitigate the problem, I suggest you to extend the original Mailer class into your namespace, and then swap the lines containing `addContent` and `callMessageBuilder` and then create an issue on laravel's issue tracker stating why doing so can come in handy. You final code will look something like this:

```
 /**
 * Send a new message using a view.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $view
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @return mixed
 */
public function send($view, array $data, $callback)
{
    // First we need to parse the view, which could either be a string or an array
    // containing both an HTML and plain text versions of the view which should
    // be used when sending an e-mail. We will extract both of them out here.
    list($view, $plain, $raw) = $this->parseView($view);

    $data['message'] = $message = $this->createMessage();

    // Once we have retrieved the view content for the e-mail we will set the body
    // of this message using the HTML type, which will provide a simple wrapper
    // to creating view based emails that are able to receive arrays of data.
    $this->addContent($message, $view, $plain, $raw, $data);

    $this->callMessageBuilder($callback, $message);

    $message = $message->getSwiftMessage();

    return $this->sendSwiftMessage($message);
}
```

And the code in your controller will look something like this:

```
\Mail::send('nada', array(), function($message) use($icalendar)
{
    $message->from('from@email.com', 'Arun Poudel');
    $message->to('to@email.com')->subject('Test Calendar Event');

    $encoder = \Swift_Encoding::get7BitEncoding();
    $message->setEncoder($encoder);

    $message->addPart($icalendar, 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST', 'iso-8859-1');
});
```

NOTE: This code works with gmail's email and also with Outlook 14.0 on OSX, let me know if you need some other help.